# How to get current Exposure for Camera2 API in android

Tags: android, android-camera

In `android.hardware.Camera` old, I use code below get current Exposure and get it for *Camera*

```
Camera.Parameters param = mCamera.getParameters();
currentExposure += param.getExposureCompensationStep();
param.setExposureCompensation((int) currentExposure);
Timber.d("exposure:" + currentExposure);
mCamera.setParameters(param);
```

How to use it for `Camera2` **API** new. Please. Help me!

Answer (score 3):

1. There must be a call `captureSession.setRepeatingRequest(request, captureCallback, ...);` in your code.
2. `CaptureResult` instance is passed to this `captureCallback`.
3. You can continuously get exposure (in nanoseconds) from `CaptureResult` via key `CaptureResult.SENSOR_EXPOSURE_TIME`.

Comment: it's possible for devices with support level > LEGACY. Values will be available in onCaptureCompleted callback

Answer (score 0):

Try this for Camera  Characteristics.

`mCameraCharacteristics.get(CameraCharacteristics.CONTROL_AE_COMPENSATION_STEP);`

Comment: You can explain more clearly.
ex: how to set it for camera2?

Answer (score 0):

```
 public void setExposure(double exposureAdjustment) {

        CameraManager manager = (CameraManager) getSystemService(Context.CAMERA_SERVICE);
        String[] cameraIds = new String[0];
        try {
            cameraIds = manager.getCameraIdList();
        } catch (CameraAccessException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        CameraCharacteristics cameraCharacteristics = null;
        try {
            cameraCharacteristics = manager.getCameraCharacteristics(cameraIds[0]);
        } catch (CameraAccessException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        requestBuilder.set(CaptureRequest.CONTROL_MODE, CameraMetadata.CONTROL_MODE_AUTO);
        requestBuilder.set(CaptureRequest.CONTROL_AE_MODE, CaptureRequest.CONTROL_AE_MODE_ON);
        Range<Integer> range1 = cameraCharacteristics.get(CameraCharacteristics.CONTROL_AE_COMPENSATION_RANGE );


        Log.d(TAG,"range1" +range1);

        Integer minExposure = range1.getLower();
        Log.d(TAG,"minExposure" +minExposure);

        Integer maxExposure = range1.getUpper();
        Log.d(TAG,"maxExposure" +maxExposure);


        if (minExposure != 0 || maxExposure != 0) {
            float newCalculatedValue = 0;
            if (exposureAdjustment >= 0) {
             
                newCalculatedValue = (float) (maxExposure * exposureAdjustment);


            } else {
              
                newCalculatedValue = (float) (minExposure  * exposureAdjustment);
            }

            if (requestBuilder != null) {
                 
                requestBuilder.set(CaptureRequest.CONTROL_AE_EXPOSURE_COMPENSATION, (int) newCalculatedValue);


            }
        }
    }
```

Answer (score -2):

Try this

```
Range<Long> range = mCameraCharacteristics.get(CameraCharacteristics.SENSOR_INFO_EXPOSURE_TIME_RANGE);
```

Comment: You can explain more clearly.
ex: how to set it for camera2?

Comment: check this tutorial and after you get `CameraCharacteristics characteristics = manager.getCameraCharacteristics(cameraDevice.getId());` you should call this method from my answer. Here's tutorial https://inducesmile.com/android/android-camera2-api-example-tutorial/

Comment: The question is about how to get current exposure.

Answer (score -2):

> In camera 2 api you have to define camera manger

```
private android.hardware.camera2.CameraManager manager;

//better to add inside constructor
manager = (android.hardware.camera2.CameraManager) mContext.getSystemService(Context.CAMERA_SERVICE);
```

> Next steps You can get camera characteristics like this

```
    for (String cameraId : manager.getCameraIdList()) {
         CameraCharacteristics characteristics = manager.getCameraCharacteristics(cameraId);

         //get camera mode
         Integer facing = characteristics.get(CameraCharacteristics.LENS_FACING);

         //getting Stream configuration 
         StreamConfigurationMap map = characteristics.get(CameraCharacteristics.SCALER_STREAM_CONFIGURATION_MAP);
        }
```

Comment: Where is Exposure?

Comment: How to set it for camera2

Comment: This doesn't say anything about getting exposure