# How to listen camera exposure change in camera2 API android?

Tags: java, android, android-camera2

Is it possible for Camera2 API in Android add listener, analyse camera stream and detect when camera exposure changed, and get current value? Not taken photo time, in preview time

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Android Camera2: Auto Focus and Exposure](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46823116/android-camera2-auto-focus-and-exposure)

Comment: Thank you Abdul, but I think it isn't my solution, because I need analyse stream from camera and detect, when exposure changed, and get new value of exposure

Comment: This may help to monitor exposure in preview time: https://stackoverflow.com/a/50714272/3247455